# How to use uart in android device

Tags: android, usb, uart

I have android phone with SM5502 Micro-USB IC, which support UART. I want to communicate with this phone through usb.  According to [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-samsung-galaxy-s7-uart.3743895/) I have to find resistance to identify cable as uart cable. Function sm5502_muic_get_cable_type in driver detect type of attached cable.
[Link to source code of the driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/extcon/extcon-sm5502.c?h=v5.10.17)

Comment: If I understand right you need USB OTG cable.

Comment: @SergeyMelnik, it’s not about OTG at all, he is talking about ID pin, resistance of which to the ground defines function (initially it was for Dual Role support, but also gained charger detection and specific hardware like UART, when actually USB D+ and D- become RxD and TxD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received the answer in other forum
[image: screenshot]